# PHP Differentiate Browser Requests vs Ajax Request with same uri

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My SPA application uses the following uri structure: collection1/resource1/collection2/resource2. Collection1 in the uri represents an actual php view that is returned for the given resource1. The second collection/resource is just data that is populated via ajax on that page. It does not have an actual view.

So the uri functions in two ways:
1. User navigates to collection1/resource1/collection2/resource2 and the collection1 page should return for the given resource and then populate the collection2 section of the SPA with resource2 data via ajax.
2. The ajax call to get resource2 data follows the exact same uri as both collection (controllers) and resources are needed for the call.

The problem is, how do I differentiate a browser call for the uri vs an ajax call for the uri? The ajax request uses XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Can you specify if its a GET or a POST and use the POST for your ajax requests?

Comment: You can check if the request is CORS `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'`

Comment: I have GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE calls in my ajax requests. Do browsers consistently send HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH? What if check for the Accepts header and if it is application/json than it's an ajax call?